# Create custom HTML block using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm trying to build web site using cakephp (2.5) with some CMS features.
So, I want give a privileged to web admin to change some blocks in web pages (not cake blocks). I stuck building this feature in days. I will explain using some example below.

Example - If there are multiple pages have same image and admin want to change it time to time. so then my method view files have code segment like this.

```
<div id='image'>{{block_same_image}}</div>
```

Then before render each and every page I get page html content and search for 'block key'(*{{block_same_image}}*) using regular expression ( {{block-[a-zA-Z0-9]*}} )

If found matching one next look in database 'block' table and get matching content for block key and replace 'block key' like below.

```
 <div id='image'><img src='.....'></div>
```

After doing this i want to render html content to browser.

I also developed static page create module for this web site, so admin can create html pages and it save in database. If admin want to use above image one of that pages, then just adding {{block_same_image}}  to page content will give image tag to that page.

I have 2 questions related to this senario.

1. How can get and read html content in before rendering it.(try to view->get() function but not worked for me)
2. Is it possible to use **appcontroller** and **appmodule** to do search and replace functions. (I'm trying to apply this method to every view without change every controller and model file. Because now i have more than 60 actions)
   I'm really stuck in this. can any one help ??

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1

See this [Heady Nation](http://wp.headynation.com/cakephp-get-htmloutput-of-view-without-view-displaying-or-outputting-using-render/) post. You need to set `$this->autoRender` to `false` and instantiate a `View` object.

```
<?php
/* Make sure the controller doesn't auto render. */
$this->autoRender = false;

/* Set up new view that won't enter the ClassRegistry */ 
$view = new View($this, false);
$view->set('text', 'Hello World');
$view->viewPath = 'elements';

/* Grab output into variable without the view actually outputting! */
$view_output = $view->render('box');
```

#### Question 2 -A

You can write an arbitrary function in your app controller that uses the [Folder & File](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html) api with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');

class AppController extends Controller {

    //Your logic

    public function searchAndReplace(){

        $ViewFile = new File('../View/Tests/sample.ctp');
        $content = $ViewFile->read();
        $content = preg_replace('/something/', 'something else', $content);
        $ViewFile->write($content);

    }

}
```

#### Question 2 -B (my recomendation)

I would recommend using [code generation with bake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) for these kinds of tasks. You would:

1) Copy the `lib/Cake/Console/Templates/default` folder to `App/Console/Templates/[theme name]` (Theme name can be what ever you want)

2) Modify or create your view template with the necessary changes.

3) Run `cake bake view all` from the command line, relative to your `App` directory.

* This solution might be a step backwards that will allow for two steps forward.